# Qual é a origem da expressão "ter lata"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica, origem, português-europeu

Sou português, precisamente do norte, do distrito do Porto. E quando eu vivia ainda em Portugal costumava ouvir e dizer "este gajo tem cá uma lata", ou algo parecido.

Eu usava este tipo de expressões para indicar que uma pessoa não tinha escrúpulos, não tinha vergonha na cara, digamos.

"Ter lata", por outro lado, acho que usava-a para indicar que uma pessoa, num certo sentido, tem coragem.

A minhas perguntas são:

1. Qual é a origem da expressão "ter lata"?
2. Qual deveria ser o real significado dessa expressão, e portanto se as ocasiões onde usei essa tipo de expressão está correto ou não (e aqui fica uma rima :).

Comment: há quem diga "não tem lata, tem bidão!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse significado de ***lata*** é muito comum em Portugal e vem em qualquer dicionário. Na minha experiência e sensibilidade, confirmada pelos dicionários, não significa tanto falta de escrúpulos ou coragem, mas mais atrevimento. Vejamos por exemplo o [Aulete:](http://www.aulete.com.br/lata)

> **8.** Lus. Descaramento, desfaçatez

O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) apresenta mais nuances:

> **14** *P infrm. pej.* excessivo desembaraço; à-vontade, desinibição < *chegou com a lata que Deus lhe deu* >  **15** *P infrm. pej.* falta de vergonha; descaramento, caradurismo (B), cinismo, desfaçatez

A ocorrência mais antiga que encontrei no Google Books desta aceção de *lata* é de 1934, e ilustra muito bem o uso de lata ainda hoje:

[image]

A origem desta aceção de *lata* está quase de certeza em ***cara estanhada*** e ***cara de lata***. [*Estanhado* (Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/estanhado) significa primariamente ‘revestido de estanho’, e *lata* [(Aulete 1)](http://www.aulete.com.br/lata), ou *folha de flandres* [(Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/folha%20de%20flandres), é um «laminado de ferro estanhado». E *cara estanhada* e *cara de lata* também significam ‘sem vergonha’, possivelmente por a cara ‘revestida de estanho’ não corar de vergonha (ver abaixo). O Houaiss regista também *lata estanhada* em Portugal com o significado de «cara de sem vergonha».

*Cara estanhada* já aparece com o significado de ‘sem vergonha’ em vários dicionários do século XIX, nomeadamente no Tesouro da Língua Portuguesa do Frei Domingos Vieira de 1871 e num dicionário anónimo de 1817. *Cara de lata*, que eu não conhecia, só encontrei em dicionários do século XX [(e. g. Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lata). Parece-me muito natural que se *cara de lata* foi usado com o significado de ‘sem vergonha’, *lata* passasse por si só a significar ‘falta de vergonha, descaramento’.

Há uma outra ligação intrigante. *Lata* aparece em vários dicionários com o significado de ‘cara’ (e. g. [Aulete 6](http://www.aulete.com.br/lata), [Priberam 8](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/lata)). Encontrei este significado de *lata* pela primeira vez no dicionário de Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913, que indica que o termo é chulo. E ***ter cara*** também significa ‘não ter vergonha’. Esta aceção aparece já no Cândido de Figueiredo de 1913, «*não teve cara para me aparecer*», e no Tesouro da Língua Portuguesa de 1871, «*ter cara para tudo*». Ora é possível que *lata*, significando ‘cara’, tenha substituído *cara* na expressão *ter cara*, reforçando o significado ‘descaramento’ de *lata*. Agora como é que *lata* veio a significar *cara*? Apenas consigo pensar em *cara estanhada* e *cara de lata*, já que são as únicas expressões que encontrei que associam *cara* a *lata*.

A outra coisa intrigante é como é que *cara estanhada* veio a significar *cara sem vergonha*. Duas passagens de livros do século XIX sugerem a possibilidade de a cara parecer revestida de estanho por não corar, nomeadamente não corar de vergonha. Haveria talvez aqui uma semelhança com os termos brasileiros [*cara de pau*](http://www.aulete.com.br/cara%20de%20pau) e [*caradura* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/caradura). E tal como a cara estanhada não se deixa embaraçar, também a *goela estanhada* não se queima com a comida quente ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/estanhado) e Tesouro da Língua Portuguesa de 1871). Ficam aqui as passagens:

> Sua cara estanhada, já não córa :
>   A vergonha fugio de Roma , e poucos
>   Que alguma ainda tem , são apupados
>   [As Satyras de Decio Junio Juvenal, traduzudas por Francisco Antonio Martins Bastos, 1839.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=nl0VAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[image]